# How do i test a case where i cant reference to the same property?

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-3, model-view-controller, nunit

Test case: when i edit a customer, and repository for some reason could not update, service should return this exception.

**Method to test:**

```
  public bool EditCustomer(CustomerViewModel customerToEdit)
    {
       return  _repository.Update(customerToEdit.ToEntity());
    }

    [TestFixtureSetUp]
    public void SetUp()
    {
        this._customerRepositoryMock = Substitute.For<ICustomerRepository>();
        this._customerService = new CustomerService(this._customerRepositoryMock);
    }



[Test]
public void EditCustomerShouldReturnTrueWhenCustomerIsCreated()
{
    var c = new CustomerViewModel();

    _customerRepositoryMock.Update(c.ToEntity()).Returns(x => {throw new Exception();});


    Assert.Throws<Exception>(() => _customerService.EditCustomer(c));
}
```

This test case will ofcourse not work, because customerToEdit.ToEntity() != c.ToEntity() because they dont refer to the same object. Are there any way to test this case? Or should i rewrite whole application, and make Controllers responsible for convertion from and to entitys?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm not sure which library you are using, but using Moq you could do it in a number of ways:

```
var viewModel = new CustomerViewModel();
var customerRepositoryMock = new Mock<ICustomerRepository>();

// If you just want to test out the behavior of an exception being thrown,
// regardless of what is passed in
customerRepositoryMock
    .Setup(r => r.Update(It.IsAny<CustomerViewModel>()))
    .Throws<Exception>();

// If you need to throw an exception when the viewmodel contains certain properties
customerRepositoryMock
    .Setup(r => r.Update(It.Is<CustomerViewModel>(c => c.Id == viewModel.Id)))
    .Throws<Exception>();

// If you need to throw an exception with specific properties, and verify those
customerRepositoryMock
    .Setup(r => r.Update(It.Is<CustomerViewModel>(c => c.Id == viewModel.Id)))
    .Throws(new Exception("some message"));
```

You can then do your asserts as you already had them defined.

I omitted your `ToEntity()` method here as the point is to show you more "loose" ways of determining equality on your input parameters, such as by type or by properties, instead of just by reference.

Comment: Ah, i am using NUnit with NSubstitute. in my case i just could use ReturnsForAnyArgs as alternative. thx for head ups